# input of an arbitrary number by the user without long waiting for the extension

Tags: asterisk

Please tell me how to choose a template for the user to enter any number. Perhaps the only option is to show Asterisk the end of the set with a grid.

```
.#!
```

Answer (score 0):

X! is one digit template(X=[0-9]) without search for more input ("!")

There is no patern for #. It just end input in some apps, see app documentation.